# Getting handles data with MiniDump (DbgHelp.h)

Tags: c#, windows, handle, minidump, dbghelp

I am struggling with getting handles information via Minidump (DbgHelp.h).

I am getting a list of `MINIDUMP_HANDLE_DESCRIPTOR_2` from mapped file stream..
Then I am getting for each descriptor a `MINIDUMP_HANDLE_OBJECT_INFORMATION` by using the `ObjectInfoRva` field.

However I cannot understand what information this `MINIDUMP_HANDLE_OBJECT_INFORMATION` structure gives me, I couldn't find any examples on the web for extracting a meaningful information from the `MINIDUMP_HANDLE_OBJECT_INFORMATION`, and the documentation is not very helpful.

How can I use `MINIDUMP_HANDLE_OBJECT_INFORMATION` structure data to get a a human readable data? I mean what do I need to do with it? 
I always get 0 at `InfoType` filed which means - `MiniHandleObjectInformationNone`.

MINIDUMP_HANDLE_OBJECT_INFORMATION struct:

```
public struct MINIDUMP_HANDLE_OBJECT_INFORMATION
{
    public uint NextInfoRva;
    public MINIDUMP_HANDLE_OBJECT_INFORMATION_TYPE InfoType;
    public UInt32 SizeOfInfo;
}
```

**I've done some experiment with MINIDUMP_HANDLE_OBJECT_INFORMATION struct**

When I am getting the struct, I am capable of reading a string from the RVA address with `SizeOfInfo` size. Here I am allays getting 'Directory' as a string on all the handles descriptors that I got...

link to doc:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680375(v=vs.85).aspx

Any help will be appreciated :)

My process, on which I am trying to apply it, uses `WaitForMultipleObjects` and `WaitForSingleObject` `Kernel32` calls.

Link to my implementation:

https://github.com/Pavel-Durov/Multithreading-Debugging-Asignments/blob/master/Assignments/Assignments.Core/Handlers/MiniDumpHandler.cs

Link to **WinDbg** `!handle` command output which I execute on the same dump file:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Hjid-2dcM0aZrg5A1p5VrCBSysU_VQhynXdBAvXV29Q/edit?usp=sharing

Maybe the issue is that I don't set a valid values for my MINIDUMP_HANDLE_OBJECT_INFORMATION_TYPE enumeration, does anyone familiar with a reliable source with this enum values declaration? I didn't found anything official.

**Just to make it clear.**

In WinDbj, I get the same information as I get from the MINIDUMP_HANDLE_DESCRIPTOR_2, 
For instance if WinDbg !handle command has this output:

```
Handle 00000004
  Type                   Directory
Handle 00000008
  Type                   Directory
Handle 0000000c
  Type                   Event
Handle 00000010
  Type                   Event
Handle 00000014
  Type                   File
…
```

I can getthe same data from the `MINIDUMP_HANDLE_DESCRIPTOR_2` ObjectName and TypeName which are of `MINIDUMP_STRING` type.

The information that I **cannot** get is the one located in the `MINIDUMP_HANDLE_OBJECT_INFORMATION` struct. Which is not visible on the `!hanlde` command output.

What kind of information suppose to be located in MINIDUMP_HANDLE_OBJECT_INFORMATION ?

Comment: The most likely reason is the documented one, you simply don't have any interesting handles in the process.  You only get extra info for thread, process and mutex handles.  The rest are "no extra info", 0.

Comment: I am collecting this information on a process which waits for multiple mutexes, there is suppose to be some kind of information cause if I am looking at the process with ClrMd I get mutex names...

Comment: A managed Mutex object has nothing to do with an unmanaged one.  This table is for the benefit of a debugger, use the Windbg !handle command to compare.

Comment: Oh right, I'll try, thanks!

Comment: I've tested it on Kernel32 calls (updated the question) still, I get MiniHandleObjectInformationNone on each handle info

Comment: I've also added a link to the !handle command result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of rough hours - debugging my managed code and comparing it to C++ code examples - I found my bug with `MINIDUMP_HANDLE_OBJECT_INFORMATION` struct reading – I didn’t calculated the `rva + baseMinidump` address appropriately.

Now it works, I am able of getting the additional information the handles :)

Mu code can be found here:
https://github.com/Pavel-Durov/Multithreading-Debugging-Asignments/blob/master/Assignments/Assignments.Core/Handlers/MiniDumpHandler.cs

line 144, DealWithHandleInfo function